# In Go why is this array looped function, faster than a regular loop? (Difference of almost 50%)

Tags: performance, for-loop, go

**EDIT: Turns out this is not easy to reproduce. I think it may be a Host OS or Linux Distro issue. Trying it with different distros in Docker, but running on the same host, produces the same results.**

**EDIT 2: I altered the code in main.go. Based on the comments saying that it was the GC causing this. Now it should definitely be rewriting the value over the previous one. So there shouldn't be any GC.**

Basically there's 2 things I am trying to understand.

1. The main thing I am trying to understand why these two functions, which do the same thing in the end, are so different in speed. One of them I make the array the size of the number of hashes I want (which uses more memory), and the other one is just a for loop.
2. How could I speed up the regular for loop function to gain the speed benefit without using the extra memory? (if possible)

Results of Benchmark on my system:
The Array function completes in `3.6 seconds` and the loop function takes `6.4 seconds`.

```
go version go1.19.2 linux/amd64


goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: github.com/gngenius02/shardedmapdb
cpu: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor            
BenchmarkGetHashesArray10Million-24            1        3662003126 ns/op        2080037632 B/op 30000051 allocs/op
BenchmarkGetHashesLoop10Million-24             1        6462627155 ns/op        1920001352 B/op 30000022 allocs/op
PASS
```

The two functions in question are `GetHashUsingArray` and `GetHashUsingLoop`.

main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
)

type HashArray []string

type HS struct {
    LastHash string
    HashList HashArray
}

func (h *HS) GetHashUsingArray() {
    hashit := func(s string) string {
        digest := sha256.Sum256([]byte(s))
        return hex.EncodeToString(digest[:])
    }
    hl := h.HashList
    for i := 1; i < len(hl); i++ {
        (hl)[i] = hashit((hl)[i-1])
    }
    h.LastHash = hl[len(hl)-1]
}

func GetHashUsingLoop(s string, loops int) string {
    hashit := func(s *string) {
        digest := sha256.Sum256([]byte(*s))
        *s = hex.EncodeToString(digest[:])
    }
    hash := s
    for i := 0; i < loops; i++ {
        hashit(&hash)
    }
    return hash
}

func main() {}
```

main_test.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkGetHashUsingArray10Million(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        firstValue := "abc"
        hs := HS{"", make(HashArray, 10_000_001)}
        hs.HashList[0] = firstValue
        hs.GetHashUsingArray()
        if hs.LastHash != "bf34d93b4be2a313b06cdf9d805c5f3d140abd872c37199701fb1e43fe479923" {
            b.Error("Unexpected Result: " + hs.LastHash)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkGetHashUsingLoop10Million(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        firstValue := "abc"
        result := GetHashUsingLoop(firstValue, 10_000_000)
        if result != "bf34d93b4be2a313b06cdf9d805c5f3d140abd872c37199701fb1e43fe479923" {
            b.Error("Unexpected result: " + result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The difference is likely in GC, maybe something escaping to the heap. I would bet pre-allocating the results slice (not array) is preventing a lot of GC cycles.

Comment: @JimB: "The difference is likely in GC." Have you reproduced the OP's results? I can't.

Comment: @rocka2q: no, but I can see the the `Loop` benchmark can trigger hundreds more GC cycles

Comment: Why all the down votes does the question not make sense? So I am guessing it might be a linux distro issue? Because I tried it on another system with completely different hardware, but same os and it produced the same result. (Debian 11  - amd64)

Comment: @JimB: The B/op and allocs/op are the same. Where do the hundreds more GC cycles come from?

Comment: To all the people that can't reproduce the issue can you list your arch here please? Want to knock arch off then ill know its the OS.

Comment: @rocka2q: the individual Loop results are not stored anywhere, and will be collected. When they're stored in the slice, there is nothing to collect.

Comment: @JimB I thought the loop results are overwriting the same place in memory so why would GC need to occur?

Comment: @cigolon: a string is just a 2 word struct value. The string header is copied to the same location, but the data could be anywhere. Since the result of `hashit` escapes to the heap, it is going to be collected if possible.

Comment: @cigolon: I can't reproduce your issue. My arch is amd64 and my OS is Ubuntu 22.10 (debian_version: bookworm/sid).

Comment: @JimB: awesome explanation. Why would it be different on alternate OSes? Does the GC work different on based on the host OS? apparently its not an architecture issue since rocka2q is on a different os but same arch.

Comment: @JimB: Have you reproduced the issue?

Comment: @cigolon: If can't reproduce your issue. The results for both benchmarks are close to  identical. I don't have a GC issue.

Comment: @rocka2q: Yea it seems like it's the specific linux distro I'm using that's causing the issue.  I was trying to run the tests on repl.it before I posted but it wouldn't run the tests, I don't have a system with a different OS I could try it on.

Comment: @rocka2q, no I have not (probably bc I'm on an 8core m1). It's trivial however to just look at how much the garbage collector is running, combined with the fact that you can see the results escape to the heap with no references. It's really the only difference here, so trying to determine how that affects the OP's system if probably the best line of investigation.

Comment: @JimB: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74196597/16465802: `go version go1.18.1 darwin/arm64` and 8 cores. Do you get similar results?

Comment: @rocka2q: yes. I'm am not disputing your results, I am explaining the differences I see in the operations that each benchmark is running. The Loop benchmark will cause significantly more garbage collection cycles, which _may_ be what is affecting the OP.

Comment: I have checked go versions and different systems (same OS). Turns out its likely the host OS as the root cause of the issue. I even tried running it in docker Ubuntu:22.04 but i get the same results (not exactly but same nonetheless). Not sure exactly whats going on with that.

Comment: @JimB I altered the main code to take in a pointer to a string and overwrite it to try and get away from the GC. yet it still yields the same result on all linux OSes using my system. But on Windows it doesn't. I find it really strange that its so difficult to reproduce this.

Comment: The string header was not allocated on the heap in the original edit and is probably not allocated in the current edit.  I think the concern was about the string data, not about string header.

Comment: If you want to remove GC from the test, set GOGC=off

Comment: @JimB that did it! I finally get the same output as everyone else. Thanks for the help. I still find it strange that different systems handle GC differently though. Regardless, now that I fully know what the issue is I can research on ways to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's somehow relates to either to your own hardware or go version. On my machine results are completely different:

`go version go1.18.1 darwin/arm64`

```bash
% go test -bench=. -v 
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: github.com/foo/bar
BenchmarkGetHashUsingArray10Million
BenchmarkGetHashUsingArray10Million-8                  1        1658941791 ns/op        2080012144 B/op 30000012 allocs/op
BenchmarkGetHashUsingLoop10Million
BenchmarkGetHashUsingLoop10Million-8                   1        1391175042 ns/op        1920005816 B/op 30000063 allocs/op
PASS
```

maybe worth checking with go 1.18 to narrow the scope. I.e. if it will be the same difference with go 1.19 then it's hardware. If difference is not that huge then it's something that was introduced in go 1.19

Comment: I get essentially the same benchmark results for go1.17, go1.18, go1.19, and go1.20.

Comment: Then it looks like some specific of AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor used by @cigol-on

Comment: @2r2w I tested it on Intel system with the same OS and had the same results. So its not the hardware. It's definitely the OS. I am going to live boot Ubuntu and try it there to verify.

Comment: @rocka2q after further testing. The Xubuntu 22.04 live boot yielded same results. but then I booted into my Windows 11 and I got results similar to yours (with the same system). So now I'm not even sure what it could be anymore. AMD on linux, or high core count on linux maybe could be the cause? The other Intel system I tested it on was a 36 core system. I give up at this point. I wanted to know what the actual cause was so I can test for it and have my program run the more efficient one.